# Outputting the position of multiple array values. The position not the value itself

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a programm which output all the positions of an array that are bigger than a variable in value. So far.
I have done the following: With the scanner I define the length of the array. The second scanner is to enter the values. So if the length of the array was 5, I could for instance enter -> 5,4,3,7,8.

The main function of the programm:
Through a third scanner, I add a value. This value defines what is being outputted at the end which are all the positions of the array which are higher in value than the value that we added through the last scanner.

```
Example: INPUT: 5   1 5 3 4 2   3
         OUTPUT: 1 3
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Output_Limit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index;
        int number;
        int[] field;
        int value;
        int output;
        

        {
            number = sc.nextInt();
            field= new int[number];

        }
        index=0;
        while (index < number) {
            field[index] = sc.nextInt();

            index++;
        }

        value= sc.nextInt();
        output=0;

        if ( index < value - 1 ) System.out.println("-");
        index=index+1;
        System.out.println(index);

    }
}
```

Comment: Since the output is expected to have multiple values, don't you think you might need a loop to find them?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your output should contain multiple values, so I would suggest to use an Array or an ArrayList to store the output.
2. After you read the `value` from the scanner you have to iterate over the `field` array and check if the element is > `value` and save all the indices in your output data structure. You can use a while or for loop to achieve this

It can look like this:

```java
public class Output_Limit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index;
        int number;
        int[] field;
        int value;
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();

        number = sc.nextInt();
        field = new int[number];

        index = 0;
        while (index < number) {
            field[index] = sc.nextInt();
            index++;
        }

        value = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            if (field[i] > value) {
                output.add(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + output);
    }
}
```